# In C - How would I use scanf to store a random amount of ints to a 2d array

Tags: c, scanf

I was wondering how you would do the following:

I provide the width and height of a grid as command line arguments, and I now need to read the grid from standard input and store it into a 2d array. if the command line arguments are just standard integers and the grid is in the following format:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 ... x
1 2 3 4 5 6 ... x
1 2 3 4 5 6 ... x
. . . . . . ... x
y y y y y y  y  y
```

how would I read this? I'm getting really confused because I don't have a static number of rows and columns since the values of each can change based off user input.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. From your description…  _”I provide the width and height of a grid as command line arguments”_ … if this is the case then the columns and rows “are” static.

Comment: Which part exactly do you not know how to do? Do you know how to do dynamic allocation?  How to do that for a 2D array? How to write loops based on the input dimensions? Showing some code would help make it clearer what you have tried and what specific problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about creating your grid using command line arguments, indeed, as JohnG said, arguments are static, so your width and height are static and you can simply create an array.

Say your program is run by using the format `./program heigth width`, you just have to use:

```
int tab[atoi(argv[1])][atoi(argv[2])];
```

However, if you want to dynamically create a two-dimensional array (meaning with a width and heigth you don't know beforehand), here is an example, using `malloc` and pointers, which are two very importants parts of the C language.
Note that this isn't exactly a two-dimensional array, but a 1D array of pointers and several 1D arrays of int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    printf("Height: ");
    int height = 0;
    scanf("%d", &height);

    printf("Width: ");
    int width = 0;
    scanf("%d", &width);

    int** tab = malloc(height*sizeof(int*)); // Take the space for height * pointers of integer that points towards the first values of each line
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        tab[i] = malloc(width*sizeof(int)); // take the space for width * integers, where we will stock our values
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            tab[i][j] = j + 1; // assign the value 1, 2, 3... to each line
        }
    }

    // Print array:
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            printf("%d ",tab[i][j]); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Free memory allocated for each malloc
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        free(tab[i]);
    }
    free(tab);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will add the `atoi`. I forgot about it, thanks. Same for the array, though this one is more about me not making myself clear enough.

Comment: `int main ()` is not sanctioned by the Standard; this is at best an implementation-defined signature for `main` (instead use `int main(void)`). To pass command line arguments you need `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Also note that `argc` and `argv` are not static variables; they are automatic variables that only exist within `main`.  `int tab[atoi(argv[1])][atoi(argv[2])]` will not work unless the implementation supports VLAs (introduced with C99, and made optional with C11).